# Good Quality Book recommendation for WCF

Tags: wcf

Other posts are outdated. Please don't close my post or vote it down.

Could anyone recommend a good quality WCF book for beginner/intermediate/expert?

Belows are the books I read, but I feel that the first book is good for the first few chapters.

The second book is really good. But it does NOT have separated code example for most of the example mentioned in the book. Thus, it is difficult to test them individually. It only shows the main code on the book, and combine all code in one solution.

[Essential Windows Communication Foundation (WCF): For .NET Framework 3.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321440064)

[Programming WCF Services: Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus Juval Lowy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489)

**Edit**

Is there anyone who created the code example from the second book (Juval Lowy), and would like to share it.

Or

I need to wait for the second version for this book: [Learning WCF: A Hands-on Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627)

Comment: Programming WCF Services by Juval Lowy is great - however, slightly more geared towards the advanced WCF programmer.

Comment: thanks. I knew. I had read the whole book. But it lacks working code that can be downloaded.

Comment: If you want to download code, see my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think she has updated it for WCF 4, but Michele Bustamante's [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) is a great beginner's book. She has step by step exercises and explanations and writing style is a tad easier to read imo.

Comment: thank you for your advice. I wonder if there is a way to find out  when it will be pulished.

Comment: A lot of the stuff she goes through is still relevant. I managed to get her signature on my copy at a conference!

Comment: That is cool! Is there any chance you can contact her regarding her next edition?

Answer (score 2):

The reason the Lowry book is a bit short on code is because his [posted iDesign course material](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) is so good. If you've read the book through and are hungry for more, I'd say stop reading and start running through some of these examples.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If it is that good. It should provide the code as well, which makes it perfect. I think I should ask anyone who has done that already. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your link. Are those example for the book?

Comment: those example might be helpful. Thanks again.